# Time Machine restores and network settings

Tags: time-machine, backup, restore

Not sure if this has already been asked (I didn't find the question in my search) but I am really curious to know if a Time Machine restore restores my network settings. I have a broadband Internet connection configured on my system and don't have the settings variables written down elsewhere. And I am planning to perform a clean upgrade of my OS when 10.10 is available.

Also, does Time Machine restore any custom application-level keyboard shortcuts I might have currently active on my system? If yes, does a TM backup automatically restore these things (Internet settings and custom shortcuts)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After performing your clean install, you can launch the migration assistant and choose Time Machine as your source. This will allow you to select what to restore including Applications, Documents and Home Folder, System and Network settings, and all of your application settings. You can read more at this article on Apple's site: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5872

Comment: I cannot speak for newer OS X versions, but Migration Assistant on Lion definitely does not migrate network settings. This has been a huge PITA for me because I have a large number of client VPNs and wireless networks to which I connect. A reinstall and profile migration loses all of that.